# how can I install MongoDB as a service in centOS

Tags: linux, centos, service, mongodb

I'm new to Linux, I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) provided by the official 10gen documentation, as far I see I'm able to run mongoDB db in the console but I'd like to run it as a service.

this is what I got so far:

[image]

I've been searching on the web but most of the tutorials seems to be outdated, the linux distro is centOS **Linux version 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.openlogic.x86_64**

any advice on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install mongodb-server for CentOS using the command

```
yum install mongodb-server.
```

Once it's installed you can control the mongod service with the service command

```
service mongod start
```

for example.

Comment: I was looking at this document and it says exactly the same! http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/ thanks!

Comment: minor follow up here - the OS repos tend to get out of date, and give you older versions (freezing on the major version for example).  If you use the 10gen/MongoDB repos and packages instead (as described in the guide you linked) you will get the latest versions

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with writing simple custom init script (stored in `/etc/init.d/rc.d`) I would recommend you to install MongoDB from official rpm packages which contain it. The script itself is responsible for starting the MongoDB service at system start-up. There is MongoDB yum repository with up-to-date packages. The procedure how to use it is described [here](http://goo.gl/kIUs2).

Furthermore, the `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` script is executed by the `init` command at boot time. Adding commands to the bottom of this script is an easy way to start services instead of writing own scripts.